# How to amplify sound for a speaker?

Tags: speakers

I have a speaker which seems to have been part of a pair. On the back there is a 3.5 jack and next to it it says: "from right speaker", which I do not have. If I connect the speaker to my PC via a 3.5 jack cable the sound is barely audible, with volume on max on PC.
Is there any possibility to amplify the sound via a specific device?

Comment: This is a Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: However, to throw you a bone [as I don't see this as being really on topic anywhere on SE] what you have is the satellite speaker from some type of computer audio setup where the amplifier was in either the sub or the right speaker. This is very common for cheap sound systems. What you have there is "just a speaker". It needs an amplifier to work. Frankly it's not worth the bother of trying to find a dedicated amp if you don't already have one in the junk room you could press into service. Just buy a new set of computer speakers with a built-in amp.

Comment: Okay thanks. I thought there may be some kind of external amplifier similar to [this] (https://www.amazon.com/USB-DAC-Portable-Headphone-Amplifier/dp/B07VL9XCQ5?th=1) for headphones. Clearly, the speaker is worth nothing because it is 'just a speaker' with no amplification. Sorry for posting on wrong site.

Comment: You need a speaker amp not a headset amp. Honestly, you could buy a whole set of speakers with built-in amp for 20 bucks